# Adding windows 10: looking for advice

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I currently dual boot and ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. I would like to give windows 10 a shot but want to partition it onto a new drive instead of upgrading from windows 7.

I am wondering if anyone has done this and had success or issues?

Would I need to uninstall ubuntu then install windows 10 and reinstall ubuntu aftwards?

Any information is appreciated.

Gil

Answer (score 0):

When you install Windows, GRUB will be overwritten and you will no longer be able to boot into Ubuntu. It's easy to fix this by downloading a copy of `boot-repair` from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), burning it to a disc or USB and booting from it.

Aside from that, just use Gparted in Ubuntu to create another NTFS partition to put Windows 10 on.

It's generally best to install Windows first, but since you already have Ubuntu, this is the next best thing. Sorry for the brief answer. Comment if you need help.